# Generate admin panel automatically

Tags: python

I'm looking for python-libraries which can make autogenerated panel for administer site (like django) using models (ORM) or descriptions of tables from database.

Answer (score 0):

I dont hear about of these libraries, but you can try SqlAlchemy and WTForms.